# Imitating Facebook "closest friend" notification behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to know if it's possible to replicate the facebook "closest friend" notification mechanism ... In more pratical terms, I'd like to build an app that sends me a notification about a specific action of a selected friend, even if that friend didn't add my app ... 
Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can't send app->user notifications to users that haven't authorised your app, but you can send them from user->user using the [Requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

You could also make posts on those user's timelines using the `publish_stream` extended permission but such posts need to be user-initiated.

There's no way to send unsolicited messages to users that aren't users of your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it seems you haven't even read my question ... 
_I_ am an user of this app, _I_ want to receive update (notification) on selected friends action who aren't user of my app.
Clear now?

Comment: You want to build an app that tells you when specific friends upload new content? Just poll your /home connection, strip out the user ids and send yourself some sort of notification off-facebook or via an app-user request when something you want a notification about occurs